# Appending div to page cause entire page to jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm serving an ad through chitika, and when the ad loads the div gets appended to the page. The problem is, that when I call jquery's `.append()`, it causes the entire page to "jump" down.

This is how I'm appending the ad:

```
$('.ad-box').append('<div class="ad" id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
```

I've tried adding every CSS `position` property to the `.ad-box`, but nothing seems to preventing the jump.

If someone could help me figure out this bug, I would be very grateful.

Comment: If the div is inserted into the flow of the page, then why wouldn't the page "jump"? If you don't want the page to grow then you need to absolute position it.

Comment: I think he means that the page jumps as if someone clicked `<a href="#chitikaAdBlock-xyz"></a>`

Comment: not sure about the rest of the ad code, but is it something in the ad itself that causes the page to jump?  I don't think .append() would cause this by itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appending div causes element to scroll to bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973470/appending-div-causes-element-to-scroll-to-bottom)

Comment: @StvnW, sometimes rephrasing helps =)

Comment: @ConnorBlack I agree, but it's the original question you should rephrase. It's perfectly acceptable, whereas posting duplicates is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do

```
$('.ad-box').append('<div style="position:absolute;" class="ad" id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
                          ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

Or if you don't want that,

just try giving the `.ad-block` a min-width and min-height in your css

Comment: I thought this would work too, but it still is causing a jump. Maybe it's because the ad is contained inside a relative positioned div?

Comment: Adding a min-width and min-height to `.add-box` doesn't seem to do the trick either

Comment: Actually, first suggestion fixes the issue in firefox and safari. Now the bug only persists in chrome

Answer (score 1):

If you already know what the dimensions of the ad will be, give the parent `.ad-box` the height of the ad with CSS.

```
.ad-box {
    height:[adHeight]px;
}
```

This will prevent the ad from offsetting other elements on the page when it arrives.